# Passing parameters from one stored proc to another stored proc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to pass some parameters for a nested stored proc. Here is my scenario. `Proc1` is main stored proc. I am calling another stored proc called `Proc2` inside `Proc1`. When I am passing the same parameters for both the procs. I am getting error.

Here is my stored proc - any help will be appreciated.

```
Create Procedure Proc1(
    @fname varchar(20),
    @lname varchar(20),
    @adr varchar(40),
    @city varchar(20)

)
AS
Insert into Address(fname,lname,Adr1,City) values(@fname,@lname,@adr,@city)

exec proc2  @fname,
            @lname ,
            @adr ,
            @city
```

Comment: How does the source for `Proc2` look? (If it is long, at least post the part with the argument declaration).

Comment: Hi I figured out the issue thank you for your time

Comment: You should post your answer so other people can check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your real code, you have a couple of simple typos that will give errors:

- In the `insert` statement you have type `@laname` while the parameter is `@lname`.
- In the `insert` statement you have an extra `,` before the the last `)`.

Are this the errors you are getting, or are there others? The question lacks details enough to be able to answer.

Comment: @Henry you really should post an explanation of how you solved your issue. If not for the sake of others looking for answers but for the sake of everyone who replied here and took the time to try and help you.